# android.support.v7.widget.CardView not displaying when I run my application

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

The CardView from the layout below doesn't show up when I run my application. 
In the build.gradle file I've already added the dependencies for `GridLayout` and `AppCompat`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

and also Google Maven. There's no error when it runs. What could be the reason for this? Thank you in advance! ^_^.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#CFD8DC"
        tools:context="com.example.ninjathegreat.ligaocitysolidwastemanagementv20.MainActivity">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eswm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/eswm"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="34sp" />

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="412dp"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:padding="14dp"
                android:rowCount="3">

                <!-- Row 1 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/calendar_2"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/waste_schedule"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="#020202"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/calendar_2"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/waste_schedule"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="#020202"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/calendar_2"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/waste_schedule"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="#020202"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/info"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/information_1"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="#020202"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </GridLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: on which android device version you check?

Comment: pixel ap 21 sir

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile with 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1' to your build.gradle file and use support gridlayout. like below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="3"
    app:orientation="horizontal">

//your further layout
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```